# Image loading function not working on archive.php template

Tags: functions, categories, templates, archives, archive-template

I am using the following function to display a post thumbnail or ACF custom field image depending on the page type being viewed. This function is loaded from the `inc/template-tags.php` file in the active theme directory.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'flagstaffcounty_post_thumbnail' ) ) :
  /**
   * Displays an optional post thumbnail.
   *
   * Wraps the post thumbnail in an anchor element on index views, or a div
   * element when on single views.
   */
  function flagstaffcounty_post_thumbnail() {
    if ( post_password_required() || is_attachment() || ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        return;
    }
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) || is_search() ) : ?>
      <figure class="" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="post-thumbnail">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
      </figure><!-- .post-thumbnail -->
    <?php elseif ( is_page() ) : ?>
      <figure class="page-thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>);" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <header class="entry-header">
          <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
      </figure>
    <?php elseif ( is_category( 'news' ) ) : ?>
    <?php $image = get_field( 'taxonomy_image' ); ?>
      <figure class="tax-thumbnail" <?php if( !empty( $image ) ) : ?>style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>);"<?php endif; ?> itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <header class="entry-header">
          <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
      </figure><!-- .post-thumbnail -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
            <?php
                the_post_thumbnail(
                    'post-thumbnail',
                    array(
                        'alt' => the_title_attribute(
                            array(
                                'echo' => false,
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                );
            ?>
        </a>
        <?php
    endif;
   }
endif;
```

The function works properly on `is_singular( 'post' )` and `is_page()` page types, but it does not work on `is_category()`, either with empty parentheses or the **news** category slug provided.

The function is loaded into each page type using `<?php flagstaffcounty_post_thumbnail(); ?>`. This code is placed just after the `get_header();` include in each file. Archives are using the default `archive.php` file, pages are using the default `page.php` file, and posts are using the default `single.php` file. There are no category specific template files that could be overriding the default archive.php, though I did test `category-news.php` and `category.php`, but both did not work.

There is nothing in my `functions.php` file that could be affecting the loading of the thumbnail function on the archive pages.

Maybe I am missing something simple...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

archive.php doesn't have a featured image, so this clause will short circuit your logic immediately:

```
if ( post_password_required() || is_attachment() || ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    return;
}
```

Try moving the `has_post_thumbnail` check and your `$url` assignment inside the clauses where they make more sense - the clauses that check for `post` and `page`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I moved the archive image code into its own function and now have it working.